# How to optimize number of Doctrine queries when using an inner Join?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have to simple Entity: Log and User. 
Log has a ManyToOne relationship with Entity.

```
Log:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: LogRepository
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    message:
      type: string      
  manyToOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: User
      joinColumns:
        user_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
```

My use case is to show the list of the logs and one or two information about the user (like his name and his mail for example)

If I use the `findall` method, Symfony debug toolbar shows me that Doctrine performs a lot of queries. One query gives me the logs and one query is performed for each user! It is not good of course because I can have thousand logs in my view. I don't want to overload my database server. This problem seems very simple to solve. But I'm searching for a while and the results seems to be "bad practices".

So I began by writing a new method in the LogRepository class using the querybuilder:

```
public function getLog(){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
            ->select('l')
            ->innerJoin(
                'ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User', 'u', 
                Expr\Join::WITH,'l.user = u.id')
        ;
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I still had the same problem. I have changed the select parameters on my method to :

```
public function getLog(){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
            ->select('l','u')
            ->innerJoin('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User','u', 
                        Expr\Join::WITH,'l.user = u.id')
        ;
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Eureka? OK, I only have one query but my method didn't return only Log, BUT User too... So my Twig template crashes because my loop contains User, not only Log. When this is a User, my view crash because I want to write message fields. (Log.message exists. But User.message is not a valid field, of course)

It works pretty good, if I change one more time my method with a loop to filter my results :

```
public function getLog(){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
            ->select('l','u')
            ->innerJoin('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User','u',
                        Expr\Join::WITH,'l.user = u.id')
        ;
        //THE STRANGE LOOP
        $results = array();
        foreach ($qb->getQuery()->getResult() as $result){
            if ($result instanceof Log){
                $results[] = $result;
            }
        };
        return $results;
}
```

I have only one query, it is what I'm searching for. My twig template doesn't crash, because my array contains only Log.

So what's the matter? It works, but I think this is not the good/best practices.

Someone can explain me a better way, a better practice to use an inner join query, to minimize the performed query and have an ArrayCollection result which contains only instance of Log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should not be necessary to use the loop. Try like this:

```
public function getLog(){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->select('l','u')
        ->innerJoin('l.user', 'u');
    $logs = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    return $logs;
}
```

It should only return `$logs` with a populated (fetch joined) association user.

Comment: and - if you know how to use it and be careful: if you really only require one or two attributes of the user (and the user otherwise is a very large object) you could use the PARTIAL syntax to fetch only the required attributes of the user.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I knew that I was doing it wrong even if the job was done. Doctrine seems to be simple as my use case. And my code seems to be too complex. Thank you. It is perfect ! 
@LBA : Thanks I will have a look to the Partial Syntax. User can be a large object, and I only need his name and his mail. Avatar, blob information don't have to be retrieve. Thanks for info !